# assigned to a variable in php dynamic array by $ _POST

Tags: java, php, json, dynamic-arrays

I have an array in **Java**, I dont know how many positions

```
ArrayList<String> postparameters2send = new ArrayList<String>(); 
         for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                try{
                    for (int e=0;e<10;e++){
                        if(group[i][e]==true){
                            postparameters2send.add("1");                           
                        }else if(group[i][e]==false){
                            postparameters2send.add("0");                           
                        }
                    }                                   
                }catch(Exception e){                
                }
         }
     Post post = new Post();
        JSONArray jdata=post.getServerData(postparameters2send, "http://www.xxxxx.xx/xxx.php");//"xxxx" isnt the real name
```

and I try to do this,

```
$filtros[]= ($_POST);//here i send the array to that variable
print_r(json_encode($_POST))
foreach ($filtros as $valor) {
        $envio= mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_trans(id_usuario,id_transporte)
                             VALUES('206', '".$valor."')");         
}
   print_r(json_encode($filtros));




11-13 19:41:06.151: E/log_tag(332): Cadena JSon [{"1":"1"}]//$_POST
11-13 19:41:06.191: E/log_tag(332): Cadena JSon [{"1":"1"}]//$filtros
```

well, the problem is `$filtros` only get the **1° position** of the array
so only inserts once, the first element of the array ignoring the rest of them

```
 Cadena JSon {"1":"1","1":"0"} //i sent array[3]
 Cadena JSon {"1":"1","1":"0","0":"1"} //i sent array[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

To post an array of values in PHP, you need to append the key (form name) with square brackets [], otherwise only one value will be used.

Comment: like that [key{'value'},key{'value'},key{'value'},key{'value'},key{'value'}]

but i dont know how many ,key{'value'} i have

Comment: Just insteand of `key` use `key[]`, just append an empty pair of brackets to the key.

Comment: How does your raw request data look like? I'm not really familiar with Java so I don't know how the request it's generating looks like.

Comment: 11-14 13:58:39.062: I/System.out(814): array to send [1,1,1,0,1,0]//example

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($_POST);
     echo "</pre>";
$filtros[]= $_POST;//here i send the array to that variable
//print_r(json_encode($_POST));
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$valor) {
    $envio= mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_trans (id_usuario,id_transporte)
                             VALUES('206', '".$valor."')");
}
print_r(json_encode($filtros));


 11-14 14:15:45.233: E/log_tag(814): Cadena JSon <pre>Array
 11-14 14:15:45.233: E/log_tag(814): (
 11-14 14:15:45.233: E/log_tag(814):     [1] => 1
 11-14 14:15:45.233: E/log_tag(814):     [1] => 0
 11-14 14:15:45.233: E/log_tag(814):     [0] => 0
 11-14 14:15:45.233: E/log_tag(814): )
 11-14 14:15:45.233: E/log_tag(814): </pre>{"1":"1","1":"0","0":"0"}
```

Comment: $filtros[]= $_POST;//here i send the array to that variable
    //print_r(json_encode($_POST));
    foreach ($filtros as $valor) {
    $envio= mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_trans (id_usuario,id_transporte)VALUES('206', '".$valor."')");
    }
    print_r(json_encode($filtros));


change the foreach ?

Comment: Added the POST print, please run the file and update the post response

Comment: Cadena JSon {"1":"1","1":"0"} //i sent array[3]
    Cadena JSon {"1":"1","1":"0,"0":"1"} //i sent array[5]

Comment: comment this line `print_r(json_encode($filtros));` and send the post response

Comment: $filtros[]= $_POST;//here i send the array to that variable
 print_r(json_encode($_POST));


Cadena JSon {"1":"1","1":"0"} //i sent array[3]

 Cadena JSon {"1":"1","1":"0","0":"1"} //i sent array[5]